# AWS RDS - How to make a "read replica" of specific tables and not the whole database

Tags: microservices, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

The question sums it up basically.

I have an external (not in AWS) MySQL v5.7 database that is 40Gb (it has one table of 16Gb). This database will be imported to RDS MySQL by another team.

I will then need to have a copy of it in my microservice but not the whole DB, **just some tables** (among them, the 16Gb one).
The optimal solution would be a "read replica" of just some **columns** of various tables. 
It will need to be in constant sync with the "Master" table.
I would also like to use Aurora instead of MySQL (reason: speed & cost).

I googled for information but couldn't find anything helpful besides
[AWS Data migration service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide).

Anyone here has experience with this? And what would you suggest?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You can't have a standalone replica without RDS main instance. Moreover, Replication is asynchronous and read replica automatically gets updated whenever there is a change in the main  RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definetly use DMS service. You can use transformation rule and put db name and table name , which will help in selective migration.

Note :- Binlog_format has to be set true for any kind of source of RDS . They should also have backup enabled.

Comment: Can you give some pointers and reading materials on this context?